# PLC function block library in C++

Tags: c++, embedded, plc

I have been developing a PLC library in C++. This library shall contain among 
others multiplexer block. The multiplexer selects one input from four inputs
based on value of two control logic signals:

```
control_01 | control_02 | output
----------------------------------
    0      |     0      | input_01
    1      |     0      | input_02
    0      |     1      | input_03
    1      |     1      | input_04
```

The library will contain more blocks then multiplexer block e.g. pid controller,
filters, signal generators and so on. I have decided to declare unified interface for all these blocks:

```
namespace ControlBlocks
{

class ControlBlk{
public:

    virtual void Update(void) = 0;

private:

};

}
```

The multiplexer implements this interface in following manner:

Interface:

```
namespace ControlBlocks
{

class Mux : public ControlBlk{
public:
    Mux(uint32_t* const bitsArray, const uint32_t control_01, const uint32_t control_02,
        float* const input_01, float* const input_02, float* const input_03, float* const input_04,
        float* const output);
    virtual ~Mux();

    void Update(void);

private:

    uint32_t* m_BitsArray;
    uint32_t  m_Control01;
    uint32_t  m_Control02;
    float*    m_Input01;
    float*    m_Input02;
    float*    m_Input03;
    float*    m_Input04;
    float*    m_Output;

    int8_t GetControlValue(uint32_t* const bitsArray, const uint32_t control_01, const uint32_t control_02);

};

}
```

Implementation:

```
ControlBlocks::Mux::Mux(uint32_t* const bitsArray,
                        const uint32_t control_01, const uint32_t control_02,
                        float* const input_01, float* const input_02, float* const input_03, float* const input_04,
                        float* const output):
                        m_BitsArray{bitsArray},
                        m_Control01{control_01},
                        m_Control02{control_02},
                        m_Input01{input_01},
                        m_Input02{input_02},
                        m_Input03{input_03},
                        m_Input04{input_04},
                        m_Output{output}{

}

ControlBlocks::Mux::~Mux() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void ControlBlocks::Mux::Update(void){

    uint8_t controlValue = GetControlValue(m_BitsArray, m_Control01, m_Control02);

    switch(controlValue){

        case 0:
            *m_Output = *m_Input01;
        break;

        case 1:
            *m_Output = *m_Input02;
        break;

        case 2:
            *m_Output = *m_Input03;
        break;

        case 3:
            *m_Output = *m_Input04;
        break;

    }

}

float ControlBlocks::Mux::GetOutput(void){
    return *m_Output;
}

int8_t ControlBlocks::Mux::GetControlValue(uint32_t* const bitsArray, const uint32_t control_01, const uint32_t control_02){

    uint8_t controlValue = 0;

    if(Utils::TestBitSet(bitsArray, control_01)){
        controlValue += 1;
    }

    if(Utils::TestBitSet(bitsArray, control_02)){
        controlValue += 2;
    }

    return controlValue;

}
```

For completeness:

```
bool Utils::TestBitSet(uint32_t *bitsArray, uint32_t bit){
    uint32_t wordValue    = *(bitsArray + (bit >> 5));
    uint32_t bitPosInWord = (bit - ((bit >> 5) << 5));

    return ((wordValue & ((uint32_t)1 << bitPosInWord)) >> bitPosInWord) ? true : false;
}
```

The problem is that the multiplexer receives pointers to the inputs to be 
interconnectable with another blocks. But in some situations I would need to
pass constants i.e. constant values known in compile time into the multiplexer.
Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this. Does anybody have any idea how to
pass pointers to variables and also the compile time constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a const reference in the function, and pass the deferred pointer or  the const value when you call the function:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(const float& value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    float a = 5.2;
    float* p = new float(4.3);
    const float c = 2.1;
    constexpr float cc = 1.2;
    f(a);
    f(*p);
    f(c);
    f(cc);
    f(5.1);
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Is it possible to somehow pass floating point literal value?

Comment: Yes, sure. Just replace `int` to `float`.

Comment: I am sorry for misleading question. Let's say I would like to call f(5.0) i.e. there is no variable defined.

Comment: In this case you can use a const reference for that. `void f(const float& ref)`